# Finding the centre of the group of quaternions

Tags: group-theory

The group of quaternions is $Q = <i, j, k | i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1>$.
I know the centre of a group Q is a subgroup consisting of those elements that commute with each other. So $Z(Q) = \{x \in Q: xq=qx  \forall q \in Q\}$. The elements appear to be $1, i, j, k,-1, -i, -j, -k$. So intuitively, it looks like the centre would be $1$ or (and?) $-1$ because $1$ and $-1$ multiplied by anything will be the anything (or negative anything). Is this correct? Is there more of a process in finding the centre?

Comment: You are correct that the center is just $\{\pm 1\}$. It's easy to see this is in the center, and in this case $Q$ is small enough to invoke the theorem that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic implies $G$ is abelian to see that it must be the entire center.

Comment: Fantastic. Do you know the name of that theorem? I'm not familiar with it and would like to look it up.

Comment: It doesn't have a name. It's an exercise for every abstract algebra student at some point, you should prove it for yourself (very easy).

Answer (score 2):

The center of a ring is the set of the elements which commute with **all** the elements of the ring.  And for the quaternions it is the set of all [scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Scalar_and_vector_parts) quaternions, i.e. the quaternions $q=a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}$ with $b=c=d=0$

If we consider only the group generated by $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}$ than the center is $\{-1,1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $ij=k\ne-k=ji$, we get that neither $i$ nor $j$ belongs to the center. Similarly for $k$, $-i$, $-j$ and $-k$.

We remain with $1$ and $-1$. Do they belong to the center?

Comment: That is a good way of looking at it, thank you. To show 1 and -1 are in the centre do I have to show for each element that 1x=x1? So 1k=k=k1, 1i=i=i1, etc? And same with -1?

Comment: @J.Doe For $1$ there's no problem; for $-1$ you indeed have to go through the multiplication table. There would be another way: $Q$ is a $2$-group and every $p$-group has non trivial center. As we have excluded six elements, the other two must be in $Z(Q)$.

Comment: Okay. How do you know it is a 2-group? I haven't heard this term before.

Comment: @J.Doe If $p$ is a prime, a (finite) $p$-group is a group of order $p^n$ for some integer $n$. A very important part of (non elementary) group theory.